# How to updating data after deploying shiny app on shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I need help to learn how to update my data after deploying on shinyapps.io.
Raw data import from URL as the CSV format type. 
I would appreciate if somebody knows or provides documentation or example as a walkthrough.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

shinyapps.io is containerised.  Any data you upload to an *instance* of the app will be lost when that instance terminates.  The only way to make data available to more than just the current instance of the app is to bundle it with the package itself.

As an example: User1 uploads a file to your app.  They can use the file until they close ther app down.  Next time they use the app, they will need to upload the file again.  User2 is using a different instance of the app at the same time as User1.  User2 will NEVER have access to the file uploaded by User1.